# PC screen turned blue; display won't work anymore

Tags: video, graphics-card, display

My PC display suddenly turned blue while I was watching a YouTube video. Now it won't display anything. This is what it looked like when I turned it on again:

[image: garbled blue display]

Comment: Re-seat all of the cables. Rule out failing components: plug in another monitor, try the problem monitor on another PC , try the problem monitor on onboard video if the motherboard has one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your picture it looks like your display has failed or you have a bad video cable connection. Check and tighten all of the connections.

If the connections are not at fault, connect the display to another computer and observe whether the unwanted behavior continues. If it does, you know the display is at fault.

Alternately, you can connect a known-good display to your computer and observe whether or not the unwanted artifacts are displayed. If they are, then you've confirmed that your computer is at fault. In that case, you would need to replace your video card.